# Remove a fixed sequence of lines and everything that comes after that

Tags: sed, grep

The input is the file `input.txt`, that contains these rows

```
5
ccc
36
52
1
2
3
78
69
aaa
bb
```

The fixed sequenze of lines is this

```
1
2
3
```

I want to remove this sequence and everything that comes after that, to get only this

```
5
ccc
36
52
```

I must insert this output in `output.txt`. I think I could use both sed and grep, but I'm not able to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way (with `sed`) would be to use a 3-lines "sliding window":
print lines one at a time and quit when that particular sequence of 3 lines is in the pattern space:

```
sed -n '1N;$!N;/1\n2\n3/q;P;D' input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -v -M "^1$\n^2$\n^3$\n(.*\n)*" file
```

> -v
> , --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX.)

> -M, --multiline
>
> Allow patterns to match more than one line. When this option is given,
> patterns may usefully contain literal newline characters and internal
> occurrences of ^ and $ characters.

```
$ pcregrep  -M "^1$\n^2$\n^3$\n(.*\n)*" file
1
2
3
78
69
aaa
bb
```

The above command gets multi-line pattern and every record after that.
With `-v` option the command gives the desired output.